# how to convert the model to a cartoon

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, texture-baking

Good day. I have another question. I downloaded a model for blender. and here it is

[image]

Can someone help me to convert texture to more like a cartoon character. How can i do it. Is there a software to easy create the requirement i need. Thank you.

I've been searching for hours now but i can't find an easy way. Is there an easy way for this? thank you.

And i'm beginner in blender. I learn from doing things instead of just reading. So i have a lot of questions to ask.

I downloaded the file from here. https://open3dmodel.com/3d-models/roman-soldier-free-3d-model_11762.html

Comment: In my personal opinion, changing the texture won't be nearly enough, because 99 percent of what makes a cartoon look the way it does is the shape and proportions. I guess one could say that brighter colors are characteristic, and certainly, achieving that kind of change would require a focus on texturing. But what you really need is to remodel it. Consider that lattices make excellent modeling aids. You could also get cartoon proportions quickly by using Sculpt Mode (WITHOUT Dyntopo enabled).

Comment: There is a lot of info on cartoon look and similar render styles on https://blendernpr.org Including tutorials and shader setups you can download. (can't promise it'll be easy thuiogh; in my experience making something look nice takes some effort) : )

Comment: maybe freestyle would help? it's under render properties and adds a line around the character when rendered in eevie, i hope that that's what you mean

Comment: Can you post a reference image as part of the question? There are many styles of catoons. It would help if you guide those that might help you get what you want.

Comment: @no-can-do i updated the question. Thank you with the link for the file

Comment: @R-800 thank you for your suggestion i will try it.

Comment: @Fjoersteller and keegi. I will also try your suggestion Thank you. I will search how to do it based on your comment. Thanks